# How do i enable auto import in android studio arctic fox

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

I have tried looking but i could not find the auto import section in android studio arctic fox, and i have also followed some of the answers shown here but still to no avail

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that android studio arctic fox has auto import enabled by default